# How to know which version will be installed? If I use "go get ./..." for installing dependencies

Tags: go

How is the "go get ./..." command working?

Which version will be installed per package? Is it up to dated?

I know If I use "go mod" then I can manage specific version.
But I'm just wondering How it be working if I just use "go get ./..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to use go get, then there is no *direct* way.
go get always pulls from the HEAD of the default branch in the repository.
For go get, there is no such thing as multiple versions of a Go package.
So you have to use dep Or go mod for managing pkg versions.

Also there is http://labix.org/gopkg.in which is one way of managing versions. It simply redirects you to the actual repo and doesn't host code.

Comment: Then, sometimes some package could not be installed properly.. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give me a link of official document that is explained?

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Check this part:

When checking out or updating a package, get looks for a branch or tag that matches the locally installed version of Go. The most important rule is that if the local installation is running version "go1", get searches for a branch or tag named "go1". If no such version exists it retrieves the default branch of the package.